# Vector has undefined value even though the values have been explicitley defined

Tags: c++, vector, cout

So I have a vector of test elements (`teste`) in my code so I can check the adding and removing of elements in one of my functions. It is defined as follows:

```
std::vector<GLuint> teste = {
        0, 1, 2,
        4, 3, 5
};
```

I then later on have a function print this and the element vector produced by my function

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < TestBuffer.Elements.size(); ++i){
    std::cout << "!" << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << TestBuffer.Elements[i] << std::endl;
    std::cout << teste[i] << std::endl;
}
```

It produces the following output

```
!0
0
0
!1
1
1
!2
2
2
!3
4
4
!4
3
4294967293
!5
5
4
```

How in the heck is this happening? *NOTHING* edits `teste` after it has been defined. Also the value for `teste[4]` doesn't change (NOTE: I don't think that value is `GLuint`'s max value as a `GLuint -1` has a value of `244294967295`).

EDIT:
I'm not going to include all the code because its over 1000 lines and no one wants to read that. [Here](http://pastebin.com/bqTMXKcr) are the functions that edit `TestBuffer` (a `BufferData`) and [here](http://pastebin.com/sgEEJmGd) is where `teste` is declared and used.

Also this is using OpenGL and so a GLuint is an OpenGL unsigned int.

Comment: There's a problem in the code that you have not shown. Post a complete program that gives the problem.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I would but its 7 files, most of which have nothing to do with this part of the code (this is part of my attempt at a 3d model renderer)

Comment: Comment out parts of your code until it stops happening ... may give a clue

Comment: Can you run it under valgrind? If it detects memory errors, that most likely will be the cause.

Comment: @C.R. I had never heard of valgrind before, thanks for introducing it to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a problem with the lines:

```
//Update the value of the vertices
for(uint i = VerticesEnd; i < Vertices.size(); ++i){
  VerticesPositions[i] -= ID.VerticesSize;
}
```

in `BufferData::RemoveData`. By looking at the rest of the code, I would venture to guess that it should rather be:

```
//Update the value of the vertices
for(uint i = VerticesEnd; i < VerticesPositions.size(); ++i){
  VerticesPositions[i] -= ID.VerticesSize;
}
```

Comment: That seems to have been it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should post some more code, what is your *GlueInt* ? And what is Testbuffer.Elements?

If i do it this way it works like it should :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> teste = {
        0, 1, 2,
        4, 3, 5
    };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < teste.size(); ++i){
        std::cout << "!" << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << teste[i] << std::endl;
        cin.get();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So it must have to to with the rest of your code you didn't post, so if you want an answer post some more code.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing undefined behavior, probably caused by some other part of your program accessing an array or vector beyond its defined boundaries. It's impossible to diagnose without seeing more of your code. Given that posting your code would be impractical you're stuck finding it on your own.

In Microsoft's Visual Studio you can set a breakpoint whenever a particular memory address is modified. I've found this to be very useful when tracking down this kind of problem.